# HashMap comparing complete unequality. Same keys same order different values

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, comparison

Hi Please find below my scenario,

I have two maps key as string and value as boolean. **The keys will be same and also the order. But the values might change.**

I need to compare both the maps and if value changes for all the keys then i should stop.

how to do this comparison ?

```
Map <String,Boolean> map1 = new TreeMap<String,Boolean>();
map1.put("String1", true);
map1.put("String2", true);
```

**Possibilities of map2**

**1. Values same as in map1. Should not stop**

```
Map <String,Boolean> map2 = new TreeMap<String,Boolean>();
map1.put("String1", true);
map1.put("String2", true);
```

**2. one value [String2] changed when compared to map1. Should not stop**

```
Map <String,Boolean> map2 = new TreeMap<String,Boolean>();
map1.put("String1", true);
map1.put("String2", false);
```

**3. both values changed when compared to map1. Should stop here**

```
Map <String,Boolean> map2 = new TreeMap<String,Boolean>();
map1.put("String1", false);
map1.put("String2", false);
```

Sorry i am new so i posted in comment as reply.

I am planning to iterate through the maps and do the checks. Before doing that just want to check whether any other neat way to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the difficulty you're facing? Note that the title says HashMap and the question says TreeMap (although the solution would be identical)

Comment: The code as shown uses TreeMaps, so if you pull an iterator off of them, you can step through them an item at a time and stop the moment one of them matches. If you get to the end, then none of them match, and your condition is satisfied. TreeMaps are key here, because HashMaps can change order if the # of items in the HashMap changes significantly, causing re-forming of the underlying hash table.

Comment: @jbnizet I have tried usual iteration and playing with boolean value. like

Comment: Post what you tried **in the question**. Not in comments.

Comment: @argoc is checking manually iterations is the only way or we have much cleaner approach without much loops ?

Comment: @Gopi it can be checked in a single line of code (doing a single loop internally). The fact that it's a TreeMap should be irrelevant.

Comment: @JBNizet I used TreeMap to get the sorting.

Comment: I'm not saying that you shouldn't use TreeMap. What I'm saying is that you can solve this using a single line of code, which would work the same way whether the map is a HashMap or a TreeMap. Any Map would do. To answer your question, yes, you need a loop (or a higher-level method which loops).

Comment: @JBNizet got your point. any help on that single line of code ? thanks

Comment: I would like to see your best attempt at solving this simple problem, first.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry I had pseudocode but could not post yesterday as my work time was over and i did not check in my home. Generally i will have a pseudocode and if that doesn't satisfy me as good one then i will check stackoverflow or other sites for general opinion. henceforth i will post my pseudocode also along with my question. thanks a lot for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Not sure why the question was down voted ?? I am new. kindly guide if something wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering both map having exact no of keys

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Map map1 = new TreeMap();

        map1.put("String1", true);

        map1.put("String2", true);

        Map map2 = new TreeMap();

        map2.put("String1", false);

        map2.put("String2", false);

        Set keys = map1.keySet();
        boolean stop = true;
        for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
        {
            String key = (String) i.next();
            boolean value1 = (boolean) map1.get(key);
            boolean value2 = (boolean) map2.get(key);

            if (value1 == value2)
            {
                stop = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (stop)
            System.out.println("All values are different");
    }
```

Comment: You could stop iterating as soon as you find two equal values. No need to iterate through the end. Also, you shouldn't use raw types and casts. Use a Map<String, Boolean>. Not a Map.

Comment: If all values are different then only it should stop that's why it is necessary to iterate through the end. Am i right?

Comment: The OP would like "to stop" if all values have changed. So, if at least one value hasn't changed, you know that it should not stop.

Comment: @PVR Thanks for the solution. it solves my purpose and similar to my pseudocode Which I had.

Answer (score 0):

OK. You have answers using loops and both, IMO, are perfectible, and a bit too complex. So I'll provide mine:

```
boolean allValuesChanged = 
    map2.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .allMatch(entry -> !map1.get(entry.getKey()).equals(entry.getValue()));
```

This answer

- is simple and concise
- doesn't rely on the order of the keys (and will thus work whatever the type of the maps is, provided they have the same keys)
- doesn't use raw types
- stops looping as soon as it find two equal entries

Comment: What about NPE when the key is not in map1 ?

Comment: The preconditions say that the maps have the same keys. So there's no need to check that.

Comment: Regarding Objects.equals(), It depends if it's considered normal to have null values or not. I tend to avoid nulls as much as possible, and it's generally a bug if a map contains null. If it's expected, then yes, Objects.equals() should be used.

Comment: @JBNizet Extremely Sorry for not mentioning the java version. We use java 6. I saw this feature of looping while i read java 8.